# Deprotected .p12 private key file

Tags: security, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, private-key, pem

I use apn node.js module to send Apple Push Notification but it does not work.

In the configuration, I use my key and certificate in .pem format but the key is protected. 
I have created this key.pem file from key.p12 file.
I'd like to deprotect the key so I do not have to enter passphrase.
I did not find how to do this, any idea ?

Comment: do you use node-apn module? I have a combined .p12 file, may I use this directly?

Comment: I had some problem with node-apn at the beginning so I switched to apns-node (https://github.com/jpoz/apns-node), that is working fine. I need to check with node-apn once again though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
Once the key is in .pem file, I just needed to issue the following command:

```
openssl rsa -out deprotected_key.pem -in key.pem
```